# How to write an SQL query joining on datetime for each row

Tags: sql, aggregate, amazon-redshift, analytics

I have the following data of data with news (Each article with a publication date and time) and views (Recording each view at a particular timestamp):

```
news

id, published_timestamp
1, 2018-11-16 13:30:24
2, 2018-12-03 13:59:56
...
```

```
views

view_id, post_id, viewed_timestamp
a, 1, 2018-11-16 13:30:24
b, 1, 2018-11-16 13:30:25
c, 1, 2018-11-16 13:30:26
d, 2, 2018-12-03 13:59:56
e, 2, 2018-12-03 13:59:57
f, 2, 2018-12-05 13:59:57
...
```

Getting lifetime views of each news article would be simply:

```
SELECT 
post_id, count(view_id) 
FROM views 
GROUP BY post_id
```

How do I write an SQL query (I'm using AWS Redshift) that can join the views relative to the published datetime? For example, I want to get only views for each article within 1 day of its posting.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: share sample output

Comment: good point @jarlh i didn't notice the `sql` only tag, guess i clicked sql instead of mysql in mine watched tags.

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL standard would say `EXTRACT()` to parse `DATETIME` datetype as the question is tagged with sql but like @jarlh suggested you should tag your used RDMS

Comment: Thanks for asking, I'm querying from AWS Redshift.

Comment: As it is not clear if you want to join on the complet datetime format or just a part of it.. AWS Redshift seams to also be using [EXTRACT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_EXTRACT_function.html) .. So most likely you can do   something like `INNER JOIN ... ON EXTRACT(day, news.published_timestamp) = EXTRACT(day, views.viewed_timestamp)` keep in mind i don't know AWS Redshift  and don't how it will optimize it if those columns are indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this

```
select n.id, n.published_timestamp,
       count(v.post_id) as views__within_1_day_of_post
from news as n
left join views as v on n.id=v.post_id 
                    and v.viewed_timestamp between n.published_timestamp and n.published_timestamp + interval '1 day'
group by 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT V.post_id,  count(V.view_id)
FROM views as V INNER JOIN news as N on N.id = V.post_id
WHERE Date(N.published_timestamp) = Date(V.viewed_timestamp)
GROUP BY V.post_id
```

1. Here the Inner Join gets all the views records of post.
2. the **Date()** function gets the Date value only from the **DATETIME** Column
3. in the **WHERE** clause I checked, if publish date and view date are same to filter out other days
4. then the **GROUP BY** will count the views records, which is only for the published day

Comment: it would be great if you could explain your solution so that others could understand it too